# how to pass geometric point as parameter in postgres function?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, postgresql-9.1

I have some function where I need to pass a point datatype .

```
somefunc("United States",Point(85.327892 27.703744))
```

But I am getting error with this.

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "27.703744"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 1192
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try add a comma between the function params?

```
somefunc("United States",Point(85.327892, 27.703744))
```

Comment: This seem to work .
I have FUNCTION getRegions(location text, pt Point) .
now 
SELECT * FROM locations WHERE contains((GEOMETRY),pt) . Does not seem to work . It says
function contains(geometry, point) does not exist . 
can't I check if a point is contained in a geometry ?

Comment: I assume you don't use postgis, but those simple geometries from postgres, is that right?

Comment: WHERE Contains((GEOMETRY),(GeomFromText(location))) is working fine. I am using postgis. I created the database with postgis template .

Answer (score 2):

I sense some confusion between PostGIS and PostgreSQL's [geometric data types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-geometric.html). If you are using PostGIS, you need the [`ST_MakePoint` function](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html), which is perfect for parameters:

```
SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint($lon, $lat), 4326)) AS geom;
```